# show manager approve documents tHRough store procedure

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a scenario that when any user first upload document then this go for approval first to supervisor then when supervisor approve/reject documents then only approve documents go to manager then again when manager approve/reject document then only approve document shows to director for final approval

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ALLDOCUMNETS]
AS
 begin
SELECT DocumentInfo.DocID as DocumentID, 
dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName as DocumentName,
dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile as FileUploaded, 
dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedBy as UploadedBy,
dbo.Userss.Email as UserEmail,
dbo.DocType.DocType as Document, 
dbo.Department.DepType as Department ,
dbo.Approval.AppoveBy, 

dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType as Status

FROM dbo.Department
left JOIN dbo.DocumentInfo
ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID=dbo.Department.DepID 

left JOIN dbo.DocType
     ON  dbo.DocumentInfo.DocTypeID=dbo.DocType.DocTypeID
 inner JOIN dbo.Userss on Userss.UserName =dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedBy 

  inner join  dbo.Approval ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID = dbo.Approval.DocID INNER JOIN
    dbo.ApproveType ON dbo.Approval.ApproveID = dbo.ApproveType.ApproveID 
  AND  dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType = 'Approve'  
  left join Designation on dbo.Userss.DesigID=dbo.Designation.DesigID

 WHERE designation.DesigType = 'Manager'
```

end

see this image 
[record in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2kS6.png)

here in above picture record kanez is manager and sundus is supervisor

here i want to show only kanez approve documents show to director then he will be able to final approval but here both supervisor and manager documents go to director but i want to show only kanez document approve documents to director??

TABLES
[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yvGC.png)
table viewS

how i done this?

designation table 
this is my designation table

```
 DesignID DesigType
 1        SuperVisor
 2        Manager
 3        Director
  4       BasicUsers
```

and this is my approval table

```
SeqNo DocID ApproveID AppoveBy    ApproveDate
 258   30     1          sundus 2013-12-25 18:33:36.373
 259    30    1          kaneez 2013-12-25 18:34:47.347
```

now please tell me what can i do

Comment: Not an Answer but just a POINTER,,,,,, You are doing `LEFT JOIN` 1st and then `INNER JOIN` means all the non matching records will be filtered out with this INNER JOIN you need to change the order of the joins, do all the INNER JOINS 1st and then the left or right joins.

Comment: ok....but how i show documents to director who approve only by manager..and then further director go for approval

Comment: Why are both SQL Server and MySql tagged here?

Comment: because stackoverflow suggest me to add this...

Comment: Can you also show the USER table schema ? Its very simple I dont know why you finding it difficult to do :)

Answer (score 0):

Add to your query :

```
inner JOIN dbo.Userss on Userss.UserName =dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedBy
                       AND UserTypeId = manger
```

Comment: manager is in designation table and column name is desginationtype

Answer (score 0):

Now again since I do not know the exact schema of all you tables I am only guessing on that your `Users table` has a field for `DesignID`, I have Created a Variable `@ApprovedBy` in your procedure, now if you want to get all the approved documents from a certain level of people all you need to do is pass the `Designation` as a Parameter to your procedure and it will pull out all the documents approved by that level of employees.

Also check the spelling of Users Table as you have used Userss with double s not sure if this is really the case or you misspelled it.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ALLDOCUMNETS]
@ApprovedBy VARCHAR(50)
AS
 BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
            DocumentInfo.DocID as DocumentID, 
            dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName as DocumentName,
            dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile as FileUploaded, 
            dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedBy as UploadedBy,
            dbo.Userss.Email as UserEmail,
            dbo.DocType.DocType as Document, 
            dbo.Department.DepType as Department ,
            dbo.Approval.AppoveBy, 
            dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType as Status

    FROM dbo.Department INNER JOIN dbo.DocumentInfo
    ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID = dbo.Department.DepID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.DocType
    ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocTypeID = dbo.DocType.DocTypeID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Userss 
    ON Userss.UserName =dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedBy 
    INNER JOIN  dbo.Approval 
    ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID = dbo.Approval.DocID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.ApproveType 
    ON dbo.Approval.ApproveID = dbo.ApproveType.ApproveID 
    LEFT JOIN Designation 
    ON dbo.Userss.DesigID=dbo.Designation.DesigID
    WHERE designation.DesigType = 'Manager'
    AND  dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType = 'Approve'  
    AND dbo.Approval.AppoveBy IN (SELECT UserName 
                                  FROM Userss.UserName INNER JOIN designation 
                                  ON Userss.DesignID = designation.DesignID
                                  WHERE designation.DesigType = @ApprovedBy)
END
```

**Calling the Proc**

to get all the documents approved by a manager just do something like ...

```
  EXECUTE dbo.ALLDOCUMNETS @ApprovedBy = 'Manager'
```

to get all the documents approved by a Supervisor just do something like ...

```
  EXECUTE dbo.ALLDOCUMNETS @ApprovedBy = 'Supervisor'
```

and so on.....

Comment: please see my update question when i try this it can not return me any row

Comment: bring this `dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType = 'Approve'` in your where clause . you are not actually joining your table on this field. so oyu need to take it out from your ON clause on your join.

Comment: ok now i try this ..WHERE designation.DesigType = 'Manager' AND  dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType = 'Approve' 
but it always not return any record

Comment: see my update question i add two more table please check

Comment: @user3134694 have a look now I have updated my answer and if this answers helps you, please accept the answer thank you. :)